# send stringt from android over wifi and recieve in PC(java program)

Tags: java, android

I want to make simple android app in which i simply have textview, and a button. on clicking that button, string in textview is broadcast and received at PC.  am new to android programming and network programming.
1. Please suggest what tool to be used in PC. 
2. Some simple steps to achieve this.
3. some healthy tutorials to understand things better.

Sorry if i sound stupid :P
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Three simple steps: 1) Learn Java and how it works on Android. 2) Try it yourself. 3) If you get stuck on something, come here with specific questions, posting the code you tried and where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Well it sounds like you want to jump into the world of programming `Android` head first. That's fine but you should start somewhere. The best series of tutorials I've seen to date is at [The New Boston](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6). The videos are very easy to understand and the series is made of 200 videos. It covers everything from downloading and installing `Eclipse` (which is one tool you can use to develop `Android` apps) all the way to some pretty advanced concepts. So if you have a basic understanding you can pick and choose which videos you want to watch, if you want a full crash course just watch them all. It also has around 3000 other videos on all programming languages. Such as `Java` which you will need if you don't already know.

On the P.C. side if you don't have any live servers set up to play with I suggest downloading `XAMPP` at this link [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). It allows you to create a number of things on your own computer, all of which are free. Such as a `SQL` database with phpmyadmin and a number of other things. All in all if you watch even a few of the 200 videos at The New Boston you will have a much better understanding of what you need to do to accomplish your goals. You will also have a better understanding of what to ask for specifically in the future. Hope this helps, if you need anything else just ask

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm not sure if this is the best way but still is a way, you could use [SMB](http://jcifs.samba.org/) for android, and for the PC just a normal Java program so:

1: `for PC you could use Java (since you use Java as a topic i supose that you know how to do a single program with this programming language`

as a suggestion for achieve number 1, you could do a program that every 3-5 seconds constantly check if a empty File have data or still empty and if it has data then show a Dialog with the data, a showMessageDialog would do the job.

2: `for android use what i said first, with that you could read or write a File on the PC from your android device, of course if both the PC and android device are in the same network`

at this point, just write the String of the TextView or EditText in the File on the PC being checked by the java program, let me know if this help you or if you want more specific details, but i think with this you could do what you want. Sorry for my English, still learning it :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like **sockets** would be good for what you want to do.Basically, you'll need to have a server script/program running on the PC and the android program can send a connection request and then a packet with the string.

You'll need to create a `ServerSocket` with something like this on the server and have it listen on a port of your choosing.

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    int port = 9876;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.out.printf("Could not listen on port: %d", port );
            System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Often a new thread is used to accept the connection like this.

```
new Thread(new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept())).start();
```

The `run()` method of the `ServerThread` can be as simple as this

```
try {
        Scanner socketIn = new Scanner(this.clientSocket.getInputStream());
        PrintWriter socketOut = new 

        PrintWriter(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        while(socketIn.hasNext() {
            System.out.println(socketIn.next());
        }
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

You can create a socket on the client side (in your case on the android device) with code like this. (Note that android won't let you do this in your main thread so you'll have to create the connection in another thread.

```
public void sendRequest(final String message) {
    Log.d("test", "log");
    new Thread() { 

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {                   
                Socket socket = new     Socket(InetAddress.getByName(HOST), PORT);
                PrintWriter out = new     PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println(message);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception in thread", e.getStackTrace()+"");

            }
        }
    }.start();      
}
```

Since you're just doing this on your wifi, instead of `InetAddress.getByName(HOST)`, you can just put the local IP address of the PC. Also, if you are planning on this working always, rather than just learning and practicing around, it would be good to set up the PC with a static local IP on your network. There are plenty of tutorials for doing that on different OSs out there.

Fortunately, socket programming in java is pretty simple. You can use the `Scanner` and `Printwriter` to read and write to sockets.

Please note that I have not tested the above code, but the principle is sound.

**Here are a few sites with some info.**

1. http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/
2. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/ **I like this one**

Edit. I could only post two of the links because my rep is low.